# Catching Lost Responses In WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, exception, logging

I am having a scenario in my `WCF` application where I need to log the requests into the database upon exception I have stored my request in a dictionary and used `IsFault` to check whether my **request is fault**, if it is fault than I have logged it into the database

```
public static string key;
Dictionary<string , string> actionToReplyAction;
String value  = "";
public NLog.Logger _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)        
{
    if (reply.IsFault)
    {
        string requestAction = (string)correlationState;
        _logger.Debug("Request  :::: " + key);
        _logger.Debug("Response :::: " + reply.ToString());
    }
}

public object BeforeSendrequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    key = request.ToString();

    return null;
}
```

How can I **log the Request whenever the response is Lost**. I am new to `WCF`: if you could give me sample code it would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by lost?

Comment: If the response is Lost before it reaches AfterRecieveReply, or if the response doesnt reach to Afterrecievereply, some thing like timeoutexception

Comment: what if there is no response and then it doesnt come to afterrecievereply right....than how can i log the request whenever it doesnt go AfterRecieveReply and whenever the response is lost.

Comment: You can't at that point - it's lost.  You'd have to log it somewhere else - probably before the service sends it in `SendReply` (or whatever the method name is).  Problem with that is you'd have to log everything which is not what you want to do.

Comment: So there is no way we can catch the request when the response is lost

Comment: If we assume having a Request/Response communication pattern, the response needs to be delivered just as reliably as the request and therefore the responding party must implement an initiator mechanism that is very similar to what the requesting party implements for the original requests. The requesting party, in turn, is playing the acceptor role for the responses. If responses get lost, they must be resent by the responding party and therefore they must also be cached (and acknowledged). Both ends of a reliable messaging session  so maintain separate caches for outbound and inbound messages.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you are looking for a way to catch all uncaught exceptions. Then, you could log them in the usual way.

[This post](http://johannblais.blogspot.gr/2009/02/handling-exceptions-right-way-in-wcf.html) gives many hints regarding the exception handling in WCF. Among others, it describes how you could catch all the unhandled exceptions through WCF pipeline.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Yes you are right I am looking to Log the requests for uncaught exceptions, I was able to log only the requests for exceptions, but if there is no response than I am not able to

Comment: Glad to help. Actually, there are no requests for exceptions. An exception could only occur as a result of a request. If everything goes OK, then a response will be the result. Otherwise, the exception will be handled and logged... Anyway, you should upvote the answer. It is very important for other users navigating to your question to be able to identify a useful answer...

Comment: Sure I will upvote when i find an answer which works for me, thanks for your help.